# I need changed values on handclick from the Edit Form using custom action. How can I get it?

Tags: admin-on-rest

In the code below I want to get the form values from Edit form and sent using fetch on handleClick.

```
class GenerateButton extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        const { push, record, showNotification, values } = this.props;
        const updatedRecord = { ...record, is_approved: true };        

        fetch(`api/reports/${record.id}`, { method: 'GET', body: updatedRecord })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.blob();
            }).then(function(blob) {
                console.log(blob);                         
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                showNotification('Error: report generation failed.', 'warning')
            });
    }

    render() {
        return <RaisedButton label="Generate" onClick={this.handleClick} />;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you making a GET request when trying to update a record?

Comment: I am actually getting the records. Its just named update. The thing is I want to filter records based on some inputs in the form. But I cant get the input values when I am clicking GenerateButton.

Comment: Sir. When you ask random strangers on the internet to read your code and help you out then you should be kind enough to them to make your code understandable and straightforward. Misnaming functions and passing body inside a GET request would confuse everyone who reads this and also you when you revisit this code a month from now. Please edit your code for readability.

Comment: Your button isnt linked to the Redux state in any way. So even if the fetch returns your record AOR has no way of knowing about it.